# mvnw Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL

Tags: maven, maven-3, jhipster, mvn-repo

I'm using mvnw to run the jhispter application by ./mvnw,
when i tried to run it, it is showing issue as

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP
>   response code: 403 for URL:
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.5.4/apache-maven-3.5.4-bin.zip
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.wrapper.DefaultDownloader.downloadInternal(DefaultDownloader.java:73)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.wrapper.DefaultDownloader.download(DefaultDownloader.java:60)
>     at org.apache.maven.wrapper.Installer.createDist(Installer.java:64)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:121)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main(MavenWrapperMain.java:55)

I'm using corporate proxy and proxy settings are defined in .mvn/jvm.config

Comment: Not sure that the maven wrapper reads your file, see https://github.com/rimerosolutions/maven-wrapper-example/issues/2  Does it work if you use `mvn` rather than `mvnw` ?

Comment: when i executed using sudo mvn, i'm getting this error  [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact io.github.jhipster:jhipster-dependencies:pom:2.0.22 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Not authorized by proxy , ReasonPhrase:Proxy Authentication Required.

Comment: Why do you use sudo to run mvn ? It's not safe and should not be required at all. Have you tried the other configurations in the link I gave you?  Also the maven config for proxy is  not 
 expected in .mvn/jvm.config it should be in ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml) Check official docs https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Comment: Great thanks a lot.. Issues are solved by following your instructions..